# Create a square "mask" for UV mapping several shapes

Tags: mesh, uv, uv-image-editor

Although I have vast experience with 2D gaming/development, I'm starting with Blender and overall 3D stuff (shaders, uv mapping, etc) and I'm not very familiar with all the concepts yet, so bear with me please.

I have several small 2D shapes of various formats and sizes (think of several polygonal shapes, some even concave), but all of them are smaller than a certain size, say, 5x5.

I want my UV map to map exactly 5x5 "world units" for all those shapes, leaving a tiny padding/space for some larger shapes, and lots of padding/space for smaller shapes. Also I want the shape to be centered on the UV mapping.

Any pointers on how could I do that?

What I have tried:

- Project from View (bounds), but it leaves no padding for all shapes
- Project from View, but it seems to depend on the current zoom which doesnt seem good (but kinda doable)

Thanks

Comment: When working with consistent mapping 'from view' I use a camera view to control the way they objects line up so that the camera is the UV mapping. I work with an Orthographic camera if only working with 2d.

Comment: @CraigDJones thanks for the suggestion. I'm currently doing that approach with the camera, but it doesnt seem very exact, if it was possible to create a square with an exact size (5x5) and then tell the UV map to use that as its outer size (but don't include its vertices on the map itself) it would be the best, but I guess it isn't possible.

Comment: Have you tried through an ortho camera from top view? Manually set to match to a view of 5x5 blender units perhaps? If you use a perspective camera, there will be distortion. I work though an orthographic camera in the EZ Draw panel addon, allowing me to add 2d objects in view as masks that line up to the uv coordinate system.